# How to select old 3 records with upcoming 7 records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like

| id | event | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | event1 | 2023-02-28 |
| 2 | event2 | 2023-03-01 |
| 3 | event3 | 2023-03-05 |
| 4 | event4 | 2023-03-10 |
| 5 | event5 | 2023-03-29 |
| 6 | event6 | 2023-03-31 |
| 7 | event7 | 2023-04-01 |
| 8 | event8 | 2023-04-05 |
| 9 | event9 | 2023-04-06 |
| 10 | event10 | 2023-04-10 |
| 11 | event11 | 2023-05-01 |

Currently I'm doing with 2 different queries like below

For e.g. Today's date 29-03-2023

Q1:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM event 
 WHERE date_time < CURDATE() 
 ORDER BY date_time ASC 
 LIMIT 3;
```

Q2:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM event 
 WHERE date_time >= CURDATE() 
 ORDER BY date_time ASC 
 LIMIT 7;
```

Is it possible in single query with pagination? par page I want to 10 records

Comment: You can combine 2 queries with `UNION`

Comment: I guess you have DESC in the first query, not ASC, right?

Comment: @Evert Yes, I tried, but there is a problem with pagination when the next 10 records arrive.

Comment: @Limonka DESC start records from last

Comment: @KishanChauhan share your UNION query and describe the problem you had with it.